# How to install Sitecore 8.2u1 on Azure PaaS

Tags: azure

On http://dev.sitecore.net Sitecore has released the Sitecore 8.2 Update-1 version. This now supports Azure PaaS. However, I can not find an installation guide for an Azure PaaS setup. Anybody know if this is available?

Also, when I download the "WebDeploy package for XP0 / Single Instance configuration", this doesn't seem to be the same as a 'normal' webdeploy package I can create from Visual Studio. The content of the files do not have not the same structure. Is this a 'special' webdeploy package?

Comment: Have you tried following the existing blog posts ([**1**](https://praveenkumarsreeram.com/2016/12/06/create-sitecore-web-experience-platform-8-2-on-azure-platform-as-a-service/), [**2**](https://trayek.wordpress.com/2016/12/05/getting-started-with-sitecore-on-azure-paas/)) and using the [**ARM templates**](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates)? If you haven't, try doing that first. If you have, please describe in more detail  where you are stuck.

Comment: The Sitecore 8.2.1 Templates are also available on [Azure Marketplace](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Marketplace/GalleryFeaturedMenuItemBlade/selectedMenuItemId/home/searchQuery/Sitecore%C2%AE%20Web%20Experience%20Manager%208.2/resetMenuId/)

Comment: also this: http://blog.baslijten.com/sitecore-8-2-update-1-azure-deployments-arm-web-deploy-and-the-sitecore-azure-toolkit/

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at the blog posts. I created a install with the Azure Marketplace option. That works great. I will no experiment with the ARM version. What does the XPO package do? Do I need that with the ARM option? Or do I need another package?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to get *Sitecore on Azure* deployed in Azure PaaS.

1. Using custom built ARM Templates (See blogs suggested by Dmytro in Question comments)
2. Installing from Azure Marketplace (the focus of this answer)

### Installing Sitecore 8.2 Update-1 Azure PaaS from Marketplace

The easiest and fastest method for getting Sitecore 8.2 Update-1 up and running in Azure PaaS is to install it from the Azure Marketplace.

1. Doing a search on the Azure Marketplace for **sitecore** will reveal the Sitecore option.
2. Press ***Next*** and then fill out the handful of variables (usernames, instance names, passwords, etc.)
3. Provide a Sitecore license. (Required. Can be client or partner license)
4. Setup takes about 25 minutes to complete Azure deployment.

#### Once Deployment is Complete

Once the Azure Deployment is complete, a series of items in the Resource Group will be created for you:

- 1 Content Delivery WebApp (Including the App Service)
- 1 Content Management WebApp (Including the App Service)
- 1 Instance of Azure Search WebApp

  - Out of the "box", Sitecore on Azure PaaS comes preconfigured with Azure Search as the default search index mechanism. SOLR can be used instead through configuration change if you'd like to use SOLR instead. Lucene is NOT available as an indexing option when using Azure WebApps.
- 1 Instance of Redis Cache WebApp

  - This is used for Session Management
- 2 Instances of Azure SQL Server (PaaS)

  - One for CM Role, and One for CD Role
  - CM Role SQL Server contains Master and Core
  - CD Role SQL Server contains Web
- Application Insights for the Solution

### Things to Know

- xDB is disabled by default in the *Sitecore on Azure* PaaS WebApp deployment for Sitecore 8.2. Update-1.

  - If you want to use xDB, you must bring your own MongoDB, either through using a Virtual Machine added to the resource group, ObjectRocket, or some other hosted MongoDB solution.
  - xDB Cloud Support is not currently supported (as of the time of this answer). Slated for Q1/Q2 2017 release.
- Sitecore Product Module Support coming soon.

  - Currently SxA, ExM, PxM, and xDB Cloud are not supported on Azure WebApp Azure Marketplace deployment. Most modules will be updated sometime in the 2017 timeframe.
  - If you need to use any one of these modules, you will need to use Azure IaaS VM or Cloud Services deployment until PaaS support is released.
- The old ***Azure Module***, affectionately known as *Sitecore Azure* has been discontinued as of Sitecore 8.2 and will not be supported. Using custom ARM Templates to deploy a custom solution or the Azure Marketplace to deploy is the way going forward to have *Sitecore on Azure* PaaS.

### Available Sitecore Configurations

Currently, only **xM1** is available through Azure Marketplace as of the release of Sitecore 8.2 Update-1. Sitecore has stated that support for xM1-5 and xP1-5 through the Marketplace will be coming in Q1/Q2 of 2017.

Comment: `*affectionately* known as Sitecore Azure` :P :D

Comment: A great answer, as always! One correction: Sitecore Azure hasn't been supported starting from 8.2 Initial Release.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This makes it understandable. I created a env with the Azure Marketplace and that works great. I am going to experiment with the ARM version. Only thing that is not clear are the different web deploy packages. What is that XPO package? Do I need that one?

Comment: Direct link to the Sitecore Marketplace Azure portal here https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.AppSvc_SiteCore_xm

Comment: What does 1-5 numbers refer to? Instances?

Comment: Sitecore has tiers for pricing and architecture. So xM1 = 1 CM, 1 CD, xM2 = 1 CM, 2 CD, and scales out to 5.... same with xP.  It's mostly just marketing lingo.